Do the mapped morphisms under a functor constitute an inherent part of the functor?
I have so far heard “functor” defined along the lines of

A functor $F : A \to B$ associates to each object $X$ of $A$ an object $F ~ X$ of $B$ and to each morphism $f : X \to Y$ of $A$ a morphism $F ~ f : F ~ X \to F ~ Y$ such that $F ~ \mathbf{id}_X = \mathbf{id}_{F ~ X}$ for any object $X$ of $A$ and $F ~ (f \circ g) = F ~ f \circ F ~ g$ for morphisms $f$, $g$ of $A$

It is unclear to me if the association between morphisms is an inherent part of the functor, or if it arises from the association of objects. That is, can it be that functors $F, G : A \to B$ agree on all objects but disagree on some morphisms?
I can see four possibilities here:

A functor is only defined by its associations on objects. Every such association uniquely defines a canonical mapping of morphisms, which are the only associations functors can exhibit.
A functor is only defined by its associations on objects if there is a unique compatible mapping of morphisms. Mappings of objects where such a mapping is not unique are not functors.
A functor is only defined by its associations on objects. Every such association uniquely defines a canonical mapping of morphisms because any morphisms and objects that would not guarantee this are not categories.
A functor is defined by both its mapping of objects and its mapping of morphisms.

Which of these is correct?
So far the definitions of “functor” I have heard do not make this clear.

Please do not answer in the comments.

As the comments say, the action on morphisms is part of the data of a functor and is not generally determined by the action on objects. It is fairly straightforward to construct counterexamples.
For a situation where the action on morphisms is determined, see representability determines functoriality. A special case of this is the construction of adjoint functors from objectwise representing objects.

For this kind of question it's often a good idea to construct simple examples.
Let $A$ be the category with objects $X$ and $Y$ and one morphism $f:X\to Y$ (plus the two identity morphisms), with the composition law being the only thing it can be.
Let $B$ be the category with objects $X'$ and $Y'$ and two morphisms $g:X'\to Y'$ and $h:X'\to Y'$, plus the two identities (again with composition being the only thing it can be).
There are not very many functors $A\to B$, in fact there are exactly 4. If you write them all down you should be able to answer your question.
